# Extract the entries with the highest number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that is called Teachers and looks like this

```
TeacherID | TeacherName | Office | Department | Email
```

I basically have to show which 3 departments have the most teachers in it. I know I have to use subqueries for this and that I need to first count every TeacherID that goes into a department and basically the first SELECT will be the one in which I choose these departments. Unfortunately I can't quite figure it out. I repeat that "I think" that is how I should be looking at the problem, but I am not certain. Can anyone help provide the answer for me, please?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic query.

Comment: Oh sorry mate. Still new to this site so I did not see your comment. I think I just solved it by using
SELECT department, COUNT(department)
FROM Teachers
GROUP BY department
ORDER BY COUNT(department) DESC LIMIT 3;

Comment: . . That is pretty much the query I had in mind (although I would use `COUNT(*)`).

Comment: If you've answered your own question you might want to post it as an answer (and accept it) as the answer.

Comment: I just did that. Thanks a lot for the pointers guys! Figured I finally joined stack overflow, maybe i can get some help here and there. Have a good one, mates!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT department, COUNT(teacherid)
FROM Teachers
GROUP BY department
ORDER BY COUNT(teacherid) desc
```

This is the best answer I think but it can also be done like this

```
SELECT department, COUNT(department)
FROM Teachers
GROUP BY department
ORDER BY COUNT(department) DESC LIMIT 3
```

That's because every time a teacher is assigned to a certain department, the department appears again in the table. So I can just count the number of times a department appears and that will also give me the number of teachers in it. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score -1):

SELECT TOP 3 Department, COUNT(teacherid) FROM Teachers GROUP BY Department ORDER BY Teachers DESC

Comment: There is no TOP in Postgres

Comment: SELECT Department, COUNT(teacherid) FROM Teachers GROUP BY Department ORDER BY Teachers DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: No, it gives me an error when trying to run this. Furthermore, I think I have to first somehow maybe place the number of teachers in each department in a different variable or something to that extent.

Comment: @Ciuboss: @Stu's comment is correct, except it should be `ORDER BY count(teacherid) DESC`. The answer should be updated.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not see all your answers up until this point. I actually did it without actually counting the TeacherID because I found out that every time a department is mentioned, it automatically means a teacher is assigned to it. So I just counted the times each department is mentioned and I got there anyway. But I get the same result with your guys querries, so thanks a lot!